Confusion about filtration definition for martingale
The following definitions about filtration and martingale are from "Probability Essentials, Jean Jacod , Philip Protter, 2004, page: 211".
Consider a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ and an increasing sequence of $\sigma$-algebras $(\mathcal{F}_n)_{n\geq0}$, having the property that $\mathcal{F}_n\subset\mathcal{F}_{n+1}\subset\mathcal{F}$ for all $n\geq0$. A sequence of random variables $(X_n)_{n\geq0}$ is called a martingale if (i) $E[|X_n|]<\infty$ for each $n$, (ii) $X_n$ is $\mathcal{F}_n$ measurable for each $n$, (iii) $E[X_n|\mathcal{F}_m]=X_m$ a.s., for each $m\leq n$.
I have two questions:
(i) What are $\Omega$ and $\mathcal{F}$? Are $\Omega$ and $\mathcal{F}$ for a single random variable or the sequence of random variables $X_0, X_1, X_2, \cdots$?
(ii) How to define $\mathcal{F}_n$ and $\mathcal{F}_{n+1}$? Consider the following example given in Jean Jacod & Philip Protter. Let $\{X_n\}_{n\geq1}$ be independent with $E[|X_n|]<\infty$ and $E[X_n]=0$ for all $n=1, 2, \cdots$. For $n\geq 1$ let $\mathcal{F}_n=\sigma\{X_k;k\leq n\}$ and $S_n=\sum_{k=1}^n X_k$. Then $\{S_n\}$ is a martingale. Honestly, I didn't understand what is the exact meaning of $\mathcal{F}_n=\sigma\{X_k;k\leq n\}$. I understand what is $\sigma(C)$ where $C$ is a collection of sets, but I didn't find the explicit definitions of $\sigma\{X_k: k\leq n\}$ and $\sigma\{X_k: k\leq  n+1\}$. For me, it seems that $S_n\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ for any $S_n\in\mathcal{F}_n$ and $S_{n+1}\subseteq\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ for any $S_{n+1}\in\mathcal{F}_{n+1}$. In that case, how can we say $\mathcal{F}_n\subset\mathcal{F}_{n+1}$?

Jacod and Protter just have a martingale $X_n,.$ In your coin tossing example, what is $X_n,?$ Stating this precisely will not only tell you what $\Omega$ is, it will also answer all other questions.

@KurtG. Thanks for your reminder. I have edited the question and defined the random variables.

Is that a martingale? I don't think so.

@KurtG. You are right. I have replaced the example of tossing coins with random walk.

Better. You could have achieved that random walk by tossing a fair coin and saying you win/loose $1$ with equal probability $1/2,.$ Denote these independent gains/losses by $Y_n$ and define $X_n=\sum_{i=1}^n Y_n,.$ To answer the question what the right sample space for the sequence $(X_n)$ is: think of it. Can it possibly be $\mathbb Z,?$ No. We want to describe a whole path $n\mapsto X_n$ by an $\omega\in\Omega,.$ Thus? Edit: or let me put it this way. Perhaps you can squeeze $\Omega$ into $\mathbb Z$ but it would be simpler to take $\Omega={-1,1}^{\mathbb N},.$

@KurtG.  Many thanks for your reply. It seems that you first decompose random variables $X_n$ into $Y_1, Y_2, \cdots, Y_n$ and then discuss the sample space. Is this available for a general martingale? BTW, I have edited the post because I have further questions about defining $\mathcal{F}n$ and $\mathcal{F}{n+1}$.

You keep asking new question without even having understood what $\sigma{X_i:i\le n}$ means. I suggest that you edit the post again and strip from it what is wrong. $\Omega$ is not $\mathbb Z,.$ Then we will discuss what ${\cal F}_n$ are and why there is that hierarchy.

@KurtG. I totally agree with you.  I have edited the post. I think the key problem is that I didn't understand what $\sigma{X_i: I\leq n}$ means.


The sample space $\Omega$ must be large enough to reflect all possible
outcomes of every random variable $X_1,X_2,\dots\,.$
In the case of a fair coin toss where you win/loose $1$ with equal probabilities each toss $Y_i$ has values in $\{-1,+1\}\,.$ Your cumulative
win/loss $X_n=\sum\limits_{i=1}^nY_i$ has values in $\{-n,\dots, +n\}$
but each $X_n$ can uniquely be described by a $\pm 1$-sequence of length $n\,.$ When we do not limit the possible number of tosses the most convenient sample space is therefore $\Omega=\{-1,+1\}^{\mathbb N}\,.$

The $\sigma$-algebra ${\cal F}$ is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra
that makes all $X_n$ measurable.

The $\sigma$-algebra ${\cal F}_n$ is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra that makes $X_1,\dots,X_n$ measurable. Take this as the definition which
is the most general. This makes it also trivial that ${\cal F}_n\subset{\cal F}_{n+1}\,.$

If you insist. In the coin toss case I think we can say the following:

${\cal F}_n$ should the
$n$-fold product $\sigma$-algebra of
$$\cal A=\Big\{\emptyset,\{-1\},\{+1\},\{-1,+1\}\Big\}\,.$$
Not sure if this make it any more transparent.



Again thanks for your reply. I agree with your answers except "This makes it also trivial that $\mathcal{F}n\subset\mathcal{F}{n+1}$". By your fourth comment, $\mathcal{F}_1 = \mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{F}_2 = \mathcal{A}\otimes\mathcal{A}=\sigma({\varnothing\times\varnothing, \varnothing\times{-1}, \varnothing\times{+1}, \varnothing\times{-1, +1},
{-1}\times\varnothing, {-1}\times{-1}, {-1}\times{+1}, \cdots})$. My question could be stupid, but I think ${-1}\in\mathcal{F}_1$ and ${-1}\notin\mathcal{F}_2$. How can we say $\mathcal{F}_1\subset\mathcal{F}_2$?

This is exactly why I was not sure if that ${\cal A}$ helps. In a Jacod/Protter situation you won't even need it. Since $X_1,\dots,X_n,X_{n+1}$ are measurable w.r.t. ${\cal F}{n+1}$ we know that the smaller set of r.v.s $X_1,\dots,X_n$ is measurable w.r.t. ${\cal F}{n+1},.$ Then it must be true that ${\cal F}n\subset{\cal F}{n+1},.$ Trivial, isn't it?

Intuitively, I understand this is trivial. What makes me uncomfortable is the notation $\mathcal{F}n=\sigma{X_i:i\leq n}$. It seems to ignore completely $X{n+1}, X_{n+2}, \cdots$. Indeed I do not have knowledge of $X_{n+1}, X_{n+2}, \cdots$ at time $n$, but I cannot pretend they do not exist.

This notation reflects exactly what I was saying in words. Let that sink in and try to ignore notation. You should be able to prove that ${\cal F}n\subset{\cal F}{n+1}$ to someone on the phone. Lastly: no one said we pretend that $X_{n+1}$ etc. do not exist.  That is like saying we pretend that complex numbers don't exist when we make a statement where they are not needed.
